# I can't find <dynamic_reconfigure/server.h> in the dynamic_reconfigure package

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, header, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I'm learning ROS using the tutorial section. Right now I'm doing this one: http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/SettingUpDynamicReconfigureForANode%28cpp%29.

I understand that dynamic_reconfigure is the package with the tools I need to use, but I can't find this server.h header. I did

```
rospack find dynamic_reconfigure
```

and the path is: /opt/ros/melodic/share/dynamic_reconfigure. Then, if I do:

```
ls /opt/ros/melodic/share/dynamic_reconfigure
```

I get: **cmake  msg  package.xml  srv  templates**. No sign of server.h ! I've already built and run the node, as the tutorial suggested, and it seems to work. For example, I can find dynamic_tutorials/TutorialsConfig.h in devel/include/dynamic_tutorials.

What am I missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394120/i-can%27t-find-%3Cdynamic_reconfigure/server.h%3E-in-the-dynamic_reconfigure-package/) by [alberto](https://answers.ros.org/users/93353/alberto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2022-01-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-12**:
Hi @alberto, can you please post the exact error displayed.

**Comment by [alberto](https://answers.ros.org/users/93353/alberto/) on 2022-01-12**:
Hi @osilva, I don't have any error. I'm new to ROS, and I want to understand this thing: since the tutorial says:

```
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/server.h>
```

I expect to go in the dynamic_reconfigure directory and to find the server.h file, but there isn't any server.h in there. So how can this include work without error? Where is this server.h file? Maybe it's just a dumb question, but I can't find the answer..

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-12**:
Hi @alberto, it's part of `dynamic_reconfigure` package, check this link that shows the [source code](https://github.com/ros/dynamic_reconfigure/blob/e9f8fa8e59a06de7ae6519e0714dfcd0ffa56889/include/dynamic_reconfigure/server.h) for location of `server.h`

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-12**:
A definitely not a dumb question. It takes time to get used to how the packages work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @alberto

You may find the `server.h` file in this folder:

```
opt\ros\melodic\include\dynamic_reconfigure
```

Also you can see the [source code here](https://github.com/ros/dynamic_reconfigure/blob/e9f8fa8e59a06de7ae6519e0714dfcd0ffa56889/include/dynamic_reconfigure/server.h) for location of `server.h`

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2022-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-01-13**:
This answer would be improved if it explained the general layout of the `/opt/ros` FHS prefix. See [REP 122: Filesystem Hierarchy Standard layout changes for ROS](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0122.html) for information.

Headers are never present in `/opt/ros/$ROS_VERSION/share`. Only in `/opt/ros/$ROS_VERSION/include`.

**Comment by [alberto](https://answers.ros.org/users/93353/alberto/) on 2022-01-13**:
**Thank you both!**
Now I understand, using `rospack find` I get the path with `../share/..` and it's correct, in fact reading @gvdhoorn link, it says that: *All architecture-independent package-relative assets are explicitly installed to* share/ros-package-name. But all the headers are installed  in the *include* directory. In fact searching the `../include/..` I find the server.h. Thank you again!

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-13**:
Glad it worked out @alberto. And @gvdhoorn thank for adding the additional information and taking time to improve the answer.